# How to get screen coordinates from color detection resultant area obtained from openCV with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, color-detection, pynput

I am trying to work with a pen having green cap tip to navigate mouse cursor using webcam but how can I get the coordinates of cap image on screen so that I can give it as input to pyinput library move function.

Thanks in advance.

```
# Python program for Detection of a
# specific color(green here) using OpenCV with Python

import cv2
import numpy as np
import time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


while (1):
    # Captures the live stream frame-by-frame

    _, frame = cap.read()
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    lower_red = np.array([75, 50, 50])
    upper_red = np.array([100, 255, 255])
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask)
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
    cv2.imshow('res', res)

    **#code to output coordinates of green pen tip**

    k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

Comment: Screen coordinates can be got by other GUI Framework such as `PyQt5/PySide2/wxPython4`.

Comment: average the position of all the white points in mask and you will get the position with respect to the image... you can normalize it to 0.-1. values and then multiply this values with the resolution of your screen... this way you will get the screen coordinates...

Comment: @api55 can you please explain how to get position of white points

Comment: you can use opencv function [findNonZero](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gaed7df59a3539b4cc0fe5c9c8d7586190) in python is `points = cv2.findNonZero(mask)` being mask your BINARY image... and he result from that can be averaged with `np.mean(points, axis=0)`

Comment: thanks, yes it worked :)

Comment: I will put it as an answer then, so that people can find the answer quickier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have all the things you need, just a couple of steps more are needed:

First find the non zero points in your mask, which should represent the tip.

```
points = cv2.findNonZero(mask)
```

Then you can averaged them to have a "unique point" which represents the tip.

```
avg = np.mean(points, axis=0)
```

Now, you can normalize this into a 0-1 value which can be later be used in any resolution... or you can normalize it directly to the resolution of the screen...

```
# assuming the resolutions of the image and screen are the following
resImage = [640, 480]
resScreen = [1920, 1080]

# points are in x,y coordinates
pointInScreen = ((resScreen[0] / resImage[0]) * avg[0], (resScreen[1] / resImage[1]) * avg[1] )
```

A few things to consider, first remember that opencv coordinate system origin is on the top left side pointing down and to the right.

```
 ---->
|
|   image
|
v
```

Depending on where and how you use these point coordinates, you may need to flip the axis....

Second, in OpenCV points are in x,y and (at least the resolutions I wrote manually) are in width and height... you may have to adapt the code to cope with this if needed :)

If you have any questions just leave a comment

Comment: How do i get the cutsm resolution i trie dused.  cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 300)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 400)
    width = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
    height = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)